# When setting up login in Linux, do not use console bound terminals?

Tags: linux, tty

I encountered a problem where I specified a virtual terminal using `console=tty1`, but this terminal cannot terminate the `ping` command using `ctrl+c`. However, when I switch to another terminal using `ctrl+alt+F2/3/4/5/6`, I can terminate the ping command using `ctrl+c`. So I am considering whether it is possible to automatically switch to one of `tty2/2/3/4/5/6` during **login**, so that the `ping` command can be terminated using `ctrl+c`.